# Inflections seem to not get loaded in test environment of a rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing

I have a model named **Aggelia** (it's greek for classified ad) and have set an inflection in **RAILS_ROOT/config/initializers/inflections.rb** like so:

```
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections do |inflect|
  inflect.irregular 'aggelia', 'aggelies'
end
```

It works fine in the development environment but when I try to run the tests (only assert truths right now) every test errors with:

```
test_the_truth(UserTest):
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql::Error: Table 'market_redux_test.aggelias' doesn't exist: DELETE FROM `aggelias`
```

Seems like rails does not load the inflections when running the tests (or at least not in time).

I am using **ruby 1.8.7** on **rails 2.3.3**

Any ideas why this might be happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the bug.

Actually, the test environment loads the inflections just fine, the problem was a forgotten **aggelias.yml** which was created by *script/generate model* (possibly before I wrote the inflection rule) and triggered the search for an *aggelias* table.

[relevant lighthouse ticket](https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/1177)